# Batch file command that will run python script with parameter

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I need a batch file that will run a Python script with parameters. `-p` is a required password. `-f` is the location a backup file to be created.

Currently I have batch file below but it keeps coming back with error argument -f is required.

```
@echo off
C:\backup_tool\python.exe c:\backup_tool\backup_win.py -p "FqI%>8Ao{j15" -f c:\backup_tool\backup_VCDB.bak
pause
```

Comment: The error is coming from the python script. How would you like us to troubleshoot it without seeing it?

Comment: How is the `backup_win.py` script processing its command line arguments?

Comment: @Squashman No it's not.

Comment: You need to escape the `>` in the password string ...

Comment: I think `>` must not be escaped as it is within a double quoted string and therefore interpreted as literal character and not as redirection operator. But the percent sign must be doubled to pass a single percent sign in password string to Python script. So use as password string `"FqI%%>8Ao{j15"`.

Comment: @DavidPostill, how is that error message not coming from the python script?  CMD.exe would never output that message.

Comment: @Squashman Python could well output that message if `cmd` screws up the command line passed to python because of errors due to invalid (unescaped) characters

Comment: @Mofi: At the command prompt `echo "FqI%>8Ao{j15"` works fine. I don't think it's necessary to escape `>` or `%` characters inside double-quote delimited strings.

Comment: @martineau Percent sign on command line is interpreted different to percent sign in a batch file. Run in a command prompt window `for /?` and read why on command prompt `%I` must be used and in a batch file `%%I`. Run in a command prompt window `@echo "FqI%>8Ao{j15"` and displayed is `"FqI%>8Ao{j15"`. Put this command into a batch file `Test.bat` and run this batch file from within the command prompt window and displayed is `"FqI>8Ao{j15"`. There is no percent sign in output of batch file. Use in batch file `@echo "FqI%%>8Ao{j15"` and displayed is `"FqI%>8Ao{j15"` on execution of batch file.